# Indent/outdent on a MBP keyboard in VSC?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Unable to get the keyboard shortcuts for indent/outdent to work in VSC. 
The documented defaults of ⌘] / ⌘[ don't work (not possible with just 2 keys on MBP).
(https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

To just get a square bracket [ ] with the MBP you need to use the ALT+8 or 9 keys. So I tried those with the command key ⌘ and nothing. Anyone know the solution. I run up against these sorts of problems all the time with MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume VSC stands for Visual Studio Code:

**Indent:** Mark the lines you want an press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

**Outdent:** Mark the lines you want an press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, haha! it was that easy I expected it to be something exotic :)

Comment: Not sure how to to that, I clicked on the 'tick' and it turned green so I'm guessing thets the way to accept the answer? (my first post).